# Recursive Search in BST Traversal

Tags: go, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am confused the structure of the Binary Search Tree (BST) Traversal solution in golang. For example, when we want to get InOrderTraverse output from the below tree and output should be [1, 2, 5, 5, 10, 15, 22].

```
         10            
       /    \
      5      15
     / \       \
    2   5       22
   /
  1
```

we will first check left tree by `if tree.Left !=nil` so we can reach to the leaf node (in this case 1). Since the leaf node is `tree.Left == nil`, we simply append the value to slice `array = append(array, tree.Value).

My confusion is from here, we are now standing at the leaf node `1` and the next code is checking if there is a right node from the current node, `if tree.Right != nil{` and there is nothing since `1` is the very last node in this tree so we simply have to return array, i.e. only 1 is stored in the slice.

What is going on after we reached to the leaf node 1, and how do we move the node back/upward, from 1 to 2 or 2 to 5 for example. I am really confused how recursive function is working...

```
type BST struct {
    Value int

    Left  *BST
    Right *BST
}

func (tree *BST) InOrderTraverse(array []int) []int {
    if tree.Left != nil {
        array = tree.Left.InOrderTraverse(array)
    }   

    array = append(array, tree.Value)
    if tree.Right != nil {
        array = tree.Right.InOrderTraverse(array)
    }
    return array
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if tree.Right != nil{ and there is nothing since 1 is the very last node in this tree so we simply have to return array,

This is correct but you need to consider what called `InOrderTraverse` because this determines where execution resumes after `return`. In this case it was called from `InOrderTraverse` (for the node with value of `2`) so the next step is `array = append(array, tree.Value)` (with `tree.Value` being `2`) after which it checks that nodes right branch (nothing on that node but it will then `return` to node `5` and find a right branch).

This may be easier to understand if we add some output showing what level is being checked and what path was followed to get there:

```golang
func (tree *BST) InOrderTraverse(level int, path string, array []int) []int {
    fmt.Printf("level %d, path %s\n", level, path)
    if tree.Left != nil {
        array = tree.Left.InOrderTraverse(level +1, path + "L", array)
    }

    array = append(array, tree.Value)
    if tree.Right != nil {
        array = tree.Right.InOrderTraverse(level +1, path + "R", array)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Done at level %d, path %s\n", level, path)
    return array
}
```

This will output:

```
level 1, path 
level 2, path L
level 3, path LL
level 4, path LLL
Done at level 4, path LLL
Done at level 3, path LL
level 3, path LR
Done at level 3, path LR
Done at level 2, path L
level 2, path R
level 3, path RR
Done at level 3, path RR
Done at level 2, path R
Done at level 1, path
```

Try it in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MMfv_85qkfl). Hopefully that helps a little; recursion can be hard to get your head around but there are heaps of articles/videos available (the basic principal is the same regardless of language).

Comment: Thanks, the explanation is really clear and I now understand the concept!